# ng-options not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue trying to loop through an array of objects using ng-options.

html

```
<select class="select-width" ng-options="type as type.name for type in types">
```

js

```
$scope.types = [{name: "Advanced Yield Analysis"}, 
            {name: "Yield by Hybrid"},
            {name: "Yield by planting data"},
            {name: "Yield by soil type"},
            {name: "Yield by management zone"},
            {name: "Yield by population/seeding rate"},
            {name: "Yield by Treatment"},
            {name: "Total Yield by Grower / Location / MC"}];
```

Here is a [JS-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/15280/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to pass the `ng-model`. Ng-options will not work when you're not assigning a model.

> By default, ngModel watches the model by reference, not value. This is
>   important when binding any input directive to a model that is an
>   object or a collection.

try

```
<select class="select-width" ng-model="demo" ng-options="type as type.name for type in types"></select>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jao23qr5/)